# 2004 Buick Rainier Ignition Coil Replacement

Tags: engine, sparkplugs, buick

I have a 2004 Buick Rainier (6 cyllinder).  I just found out the 4th bank ignition coil is bad.  Seems easy enough just looking at it (I just replaced a few of the spark plugs a few nights ago with no problem).  How exactly do I replace the coil? It seems as easy as detaching the coil, and swapping it out with a new one.  Is the correct?

Answer (score 1):

You've got one coil per spark plug, on or near the plug.  It should be a plug 'n chug operation, yes, just one screw/bolt securing the coil.  There's the usual ton of threads to sort through over at [trailvoy.com](http://forums.trailvoy.com).